# Sql query to compare the result between multiple records and provide a result

Tags: sql, coalesce, aggregates

I need to write a query that will result with a "fail" condition when one test fails. Testing results are listed in the Fail and Pass columns. One manufacturer product can have many tests. My Data is like this:

```
MFG Name  | Code | Breaker | Fail | Pass
-----------------------------------------
ABC           R      2        0       1
ABC           R      1        1       0
```

Regardless of the Breaker value if one test fails, the entire batch fails.
The result I was looking for is as follows:

```
  MFG Name  | Code | Result
-------------------------------------------
ABC             R     FAIL
```

Any help or insight you can give would be appreciated.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Sql-Server, MySQL, Postgres, something else?

Comment: What exactly seems to be a problem? Why did you tag it with `coalesce`? Do you expect `NULL` values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
select      mfg_name,
            code,
            case when sum(fail) > 0 then 'FAIL' else 'PASS' end as result
from        tbl
group by    mfg_name,
            code
```

This assumes you want to show combinations of (`mfg_name` and `code` pairs with no fails as a 'PASS', for only fails you would add `having sum(fail) > 0`)

Answer (score 0):

This is an aggregation query.  Assuming `fail` only takes on two values (0 and 1):

```
select MFGName, Code,
       (case when max(fail) = 1 then 'FAIL' else 'PASS' end) as Result
from tests
group by MFGName, Code;
```

Answer (score 0):

Joeldub here you go.

```
DECLARE @isFail AS INT

@isFail = (SELECT COUNT(FAIL) FROM FIRSTTABLE WHERE MFG NAME = 'ABC' AND FAIL = 1)

IF @isFail > 0
     BEGIN
        INSERT INTO SECONTABLE(with breaker) (Result) VALUES ('FAIL') WHERE WHERE MFG Name = 'ABC'
        ---- OR IF RECORD EXISTS
        UPDATE SECONDTABLE(with breaker) Result = 'FAIL' WHERE MFG Name = 'ABC'
     END
ELSE
     BEGIN
        INSERT INTO SECONTABLE(with breaker) (Result) VALUES ('PASS') WHERE WHERE MFG Name = 'ABC'
        ---- OR IF RECORD EXISTS
        UPDATE SECONDTABLE(with breaker) Result = 'PASS' WHERE MFG Name = 'ABC'
     END
```